# Is it possible to install MiKTeX or TeX Live on Windows using portable version as a local repository?

Tags: miktex, texlive, installing, windows, portability

Assume there is a computer running Windows 7+. I have an external drive with a bunch of portable programs, among which there happen to be two directories with *complete* portable versions of MiKTeX and TeX Live for Windows (each is nearly 6 GiB in size).

Can I perform a *full* install of either TeX distro on the standalone computer having

1. minimal installer executables (say, `basic-miktex-2.9.6xxx-x64.exe` and `install-tl-windows.exe`),
2. files of the full portable install of both distros,
3. no internet connection?

I tried to point newly installed MiKTeX package manager to the location of the existing portable installation, unsuccessfully:

[image]

With TeX Live it looks like one has to use a [mirrored repository](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-mirror.html) exclusively, however I haven't found any evidences that portable installation cannot be used instead.

I'm aware that I can just copy files to the local computer and set the $PATH to something like `C:\MiKTeX\texmfs\install\miktex\bin` or `C:\TeXLive\2018\bin\win32`, but I would like to know for sure whether there is a chance to use a portable version as a local repository.

Comment: for miktex, i don't know, but  the texlive distribution doesn't contain the sources to act as a repository but why would that be preferable to simply copying the files? texlive does not need any "installation" or registry settings other than the path it is designed so that you can simply copy or share the directory

Comment: Have you tried this:   https://miktex.org/howto/deploy-miktex ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Fair enough, but I've also though of updating the packages on that computer in the future. I keep portable versions up-to-date, and copying many packages can be somewhat inefficient and/or require third-party tools like folder diff, and I'm also afraid of breaking stuff by manually overwriting packages. I'd really love to delegate the update process to package managers:)

Comment: @AndréC I'm sure it's going to work out fine, but I don't want to keep repositories on top of already available portable versions.

Comment: A local repository for miktex  has to contain files like the ones here https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So, there is no way to mimic that repository with the files from the portable install of MiKTeX?

Comment: I think the point to made here is that for most portable installations the packages are "unpacked" at some time and it is only if you keep a portable updated repository of packed files that would allow you to serve multiple users portable and fixed. this is offered as possibility via MiKTeX network install but the overheads and trauma likely outweigh the advantages unless there are a significant 5 or more installations.